# Let $M:=(\Bbb{Z}_{23},+,\cdot)$ the ring of integers modulo $23$. Is there a subset $T\subseteq M$ with $|T|=22$ such that $(T,\cdot)$ forms a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $M:=(\mathbb{Z_{23}},+,\cdot)$ the ring of integers modulo $23$. Is there a subset $T \subseteq M$ with $|T|=22$ such that $(T, \cdot)$ forms a group?

So I know what is asked here, but how to show that this exists (or I think that this does not exist?) because to show the existence one would have to prove the group axioms for each combination of the 22 elements?

Comment: The integers modulo $23$ without $0$ are a group under multiplication; $0$ must be excluded, because it has no multiplicative inverse

Comment: With small groups like this, proving the group exists just comes down to finding it

Comment: In a finite ring, each element is either invertible or a zero-divisor. So, you just need to show that there are no zero divisors. On the other hand this group $T$ is cyclic, which you can prove using [Fermat's little theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  $\Bbb Z_{23}$ is actually a special kind of ring known as a field.  Then it follows that the set of nonzero elements forms a (cyclic) multiplicative group.  It is denoted $M^*$.  This agrees with the group of units, $M^\times$, in this case.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You say: "because to show the existence one would have to prove the group axioms for each combination of the 22 elements"

This is correct. However it is not as bad as it sounds. Sometimes the key to solving a problem like this is just starting.

Suppose you first check if the group axioms are satisfied for 'all elements except the (congruence class of the) number 7'.

You will find [SPOILER ALERT] that it does not satisfy the axioms. But at that point you also see that the *reasons* that this set does not satisfy the group axioms also apply to a lot of the others and you can quickly cross 19 or 20 or 21 more subsets off of your list.

Then there are just a few left to check and the task isn't so daunting anymore.

So the lesson is: don't conclude too early that something is too much work. First start doing it and see if in the process you discover a way to speed it up. It does not always work but it works more often than you would expect.

Comment: I hope I am not sounding condescending here. I certainly didn't intend to. I speak from my own experience here, this is a lesson I learned slowly over the years.

Comment: thank you, and no don't worry I took no offense, I did not say that "it is too much work" because I am lazy, but because I knew there is always a much nicer, shorter, more elegant solution than just going through all combinations.

Comment: Yes that is true, but it is my experience that often the quickest way to *find* the nicer, shorter more elegant solution is to start working on the long, boring, stupid solution as some aspects of a problem only reveal themselves when you look at it from close up

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [Euler's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) and note that, since $23$ is prime, $\varphi (23)=23-1=22$.

Comment: thank you for the hint.